# $A= \{a,b,c\}$ and $R=\{(a,b),(b,c),(c,c)\}$. Find the transitive closure

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, relations

Please explain it to me how one can calculate $R^2$ and $R^3$.
The solution says 
$R^2 = \{(a,c), (b,c),(c,c)\}$
$R^3= \{(a,c),(b,c),(c,c)\}$.

Comment: See [Transitive closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_closure) : "the transitive closure of a binary relation $R$ on a set $A$ is the smallest relation on $A$ that contains $R$ and is transitive."

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: Note that in general, the transitive closure $R^+$ is not the same as the composition of relations $R^2$ or $R^3$.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like that $R^2=R$. Look at $(a,c)\notin R$, otherwise, there must be some $x\in \{a,b,c\}$ such that $(a,x)\in R$ and $(x,c)\in R$. It looks impossible.

Please see the definition of the [copmosition of relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_of_relations).